How do I use Odata contains method in all/any methods if I have several values a list item may contain?
I have an array of items, each of which has a field tariffId.
A separate list of tariff ids:
[123,345,567,789]

I need to filter the items by containing a part of one of these ids (not equality).
If I wanted to check the equality, the query would look like this:
qOrder.orderItems.all((qOrderItem) =>
   qOrderItem.tariffId.in(...tariffIds))
)

If I use CONTAINS method instead of IN and simply spread the array inside of it, the query only accepts the first met tariffId instead of chaining it all via OR operator like in the IN operator.
qOrder.orderItems.all((qOrderItem) =>
   qOrderItem.tariffId.contains(...tariffIds))
)

First of all, typescript doesn't let me type this way. Secondly, if I ignore ts, my query turns into orderItems/all(a:contains(a/tariffId,'9341')) containing only one of the tariffs.
Is there any way I can use ALL or ANY method with several contains queries?

Any specific reason for [tag:c#]?

Some c# fullstack developers know how to use it.

I do not exactly get what you're trying to achieve, but an array in js could be filtered like this
let arr = [123,345,567,789]
    
let Search = 3
    
arr.filter(x=> x.toString().includes(Search))

// Result: [123,345]

Please let know if it helps or provide more information
